# Are there drivers for Dell Vostro 2520?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, drivers, dell, touchpad

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 (32-bit) on my Dell Vostro 2520. When I had purchased the laptop a couple of years ago, it came with Ubuntu pre-installed (I don't remember the version though). As it is advised that you install Windows first if you want to run Windows alongside other OS, I formatted my entire disk and installed Window 7. I felt too lazy to install Ubuntu later so I just continued with Windows.

So, based on needs I installed Ubuntu today. On my first boot into the Ubuntu OS. I found the response to the touchpad a bit laggy at times. I visited the Dell website to download drivers for my system. To my surprise, I found out that the OS was not supported by Dell (maybe for my particular laptop model).

I wonder if there are device drivers for Dell Vostro 2520. If anyone has an idea regarding this or even if you ways to optimize the performance of the system, please do leave your answers and comments.

Thanks!

Comment: You can find solutions for fixing the touchpad issue for Dell Vostro at this site. You do not need any other drivers if everything works OK.

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu on your laptop and which version? I am facing issues while trying to install ubuntu on my dell vostro 2520 laptop.